# Change android:label in activity

Tags: android, mobile, android-manifest, manifest

I'm working in the project that to be a template to many apps. 
So far everything is configured via JSON. 
But I had a doubt: is It possible to change android:label via JSON? 
this should to happen at runtime.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    -> android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: You could change the value of the `app_name` string resource in strings.xml

Comment: I need to pass this value via JSON

Comment: You haven't exactly explained what "passing this via JSON" means. Is this happening at runtime? Is this during building an APK as part of a build system? Provide more details and maybe someone will have a relevant idea.

Answer (score 1):

**That is not at all possible**. It is **not possible** to modify the value of a string resource from code

But, if you want to change the **Title Bar** of an activity, you can use

```
setTitle()
```

try this

```
this.setTitle("your title");
```

**This will not change the label of the app**

Comment: this will change just activity title, but i want that change of my aplication

Comment: As i have said in my answer it is not possible..It is a fixed string in the AndroidManifest.xml file. @IgorRonner